# Why is my cd not working in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have written small bash to automate my code

```
#!/bin/bash

jhome () {
cd /home/milenko/OCCAM2DMT_V3.0/cifort
}
./Occam2D start.txt
```

The exe file is Occam2d and input file is start.txt.
When I run my script I got

```
bash a.sh
a.sh: line 6: ./Occam2D: No such file or directory
```

Why?

Comment: You didn't call `jhome`

Comment: @anubhava How to call jhome?

Comment: @RichardRublev Just write `jhome` before you `cd`.

Comment: `jhome && ./Occam2D start.txt`

Comment: @anubhava Yes,that's it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With @anubhava's comment:

```
#!/bin/bash

jhome () {
  cd /home/milenko/OCCAM2DMT_V3.0/cifort
}

# call your function to change directory
# and only if cd was successful run ./Occam2D
jhome && ./Occam2D start.txt
```